# (Dis)prove : $\operatorname{Si}(x)<\frac{\pi}{2}+\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^{\cos(x)}-\frac{x}{x+\frac{1}{\pi}}$ for $x\in(0,\infty)$

Tags: inequality, power-series, trigonometric-integrals

> Problem :

> > (Dis)prove that $x\in(0,\infty)$ then :

$$\operatorname{Si}(x)<\frac{\pi}{2}+\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^{\cos(x)}-\frac{x}{x+\frac{1}{\pi}}$$

---

---

Where $\operatorname{Si}(x)$ denotes the sinus integral

---

---

### Remark :

If true the inequality seems very interesting because the extrema are really near when $x$ increases .

I cannot find a counter-example yet .

---

---

### Some attempt :

On the other hand it seems difficult to show it .I managed to use power series as we have :

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-x^2)^k\dfrac1{(2k+1)!}=\sin(x)/x$$

Unfortunetaly I cannot conclude .

I have tried also to complete one of the side to get an equality via an infinite series .

My strategy :

$\exists x\in [1,\infty),\exists \varepsilon>0$ such that :

$$\frac{\sin^2(x)}{(2+\varepsilon)x^2}<\sin^2(x)\left(1-\sin\left(1/x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)$$

Using now this inequality and Cauchy- Schwarz inequality then $\exists a,b\in[1,\infty),\exists \varepsilon>0$

$$\int_{a}^{b}\sin^2(x)/x^2dx\leq (2+\varepsilon)\left(\int_{a}^{b}\sin^2(x)/x^2dx\int_{a}^{b}\sin^2(x)x^2\left(1-\sin\left(1/x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)^2dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Now the idea is to play using simple bound like Bernoulli's inequality to get something like :

$$f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^{\cos(x)}-\frac{x}{x+\frac{1}{\pi}}>\int_{a}^{b}f(x)h(x)dx$$

Where $h(x)$ is a  function over the positive real axis .

Then we can use something like the Grönwall's lemma .

---

---

> > Question :

---

How to (dis)prove it properly ?

Comment: the format of the post is aesthetically strange, can you edit it ?

Comment: I have seen many of your questions on this site. How do you frame such inequalities and integrals?

Comment: @SineoftheTime How ?

Comment: @LuckyChouhan In mathematics we need to works on differents problems sometime I want something and it's another thing which I come across .See also another question where the lower bound is $\arctan(x)$

Comment: @ErikSatie yeah sure! are you on discord?

Comment: @LuckyChouhan I don't know what is discord but see my edits hope you enjoy .

Comment: oh @ErikSatie Discord is a social networking app/website. I was asking to contact you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^{\cos(x)}-\frac{x}{x+\frac{1}{\pi}}-\text{Si}(x)$$

The $n^{\text{th}}$ minimum of the function is "close" to $\frac {(4n+3)\pi} 2$

$$f\left(\frac {(4n+3)\pi} 2\right)=\frac{\pi }{2}+\frac{2}{\pi ^2
   (4 n+3)+2}-\text{Si}\left(\frac{(4 n+3) \pi}{2}  \right)$$

which seems to be decent for the approximate value of the minimum.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 0 & 0.025697 & 0.025350 \\
 1 & 0.020222 & 0.020156 \\
 2 & 0.014803 & 0.014776 \\
 3 & 0.011547 & 0.011532 \\
 4 & 0.009438 & 0.009438 \\
 5 & 0.007971 & 0.007965 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Just to give an idea of the approximation, even if does not mean too much,
$$f'\left(\frac {(4n+3)\pi} 2\right)\sim \frac{ (3 n-4)\pi}{2000 n^3}$$

Expanding as series for large values of $n$ and building a Padé approximant
$$f\left(\frac {(4n+3)\pi} 2\right)=\frac{1}{2 \pi ^2 n}\frac{a n^2+b n+c } {a n^2+d n+ e }$$
whose error is $\sim \frac{1}{500 n^6}$.

The coefficients (they are all positive) are

$$a=16 \pi ^2 \left(-4+30 \pi ^2+78 \pi ^4+9 \pi ^6\right)$$
$$b=4 \pi ^2 \left(-112-108 \pi ^2+168 \pi ^4+9 \pi ^6\right)$$
$$c=16 \left(1+6 \pi ^2\right)^2$$
$$d=8 \left(9 \pi ^2 \left(-4+11 \pi ^2+32 \pi ^4+3 \pi
   ^6\right)-4\right)$$
$$e=3 \left(-80-120 \pi ^2+372 \pi ^4+414 \pi ^6+27 \pi ^8\right)$$

For $n=20$ the above truncated series gives a minimum value of $0.00237672$ while the exact minimum value is $0.00237624$

**Solution for the first minimum**

Using $x_0=\frac {3\pi}2$ and making **a single** iteration of a Newton-like method of order $n$, we have an explicit solution. Converted to decimals the results are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & x_{(n)} & \text{method} \\
 2 &  4.611592054 & \text{Newton} \\
 3 &  4.618048090 & \text{Halley} \\
 4 &  4.617520271  & \text{Householder}\\
 5 &  4.617547293  & \text{no name}\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
 \infty & 4.617545789& \text{solution}\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**The approximation**

Having computed exactly the solution of $f'(x)=0$ for $0\leq n \leq 100$, a linear regression
$$x_{(n)}=(a+b\,n)\frac \pi 2$$ leads, with $(R^2=0.99999999999835)$ to the following numbers

$$\begin{array}{l|lll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std Error} &
   \text{Confidence Interval} \\
\hline
 a & 2.9422759 & 5.93\times 10^{-5} &  \{2.9421582,2.9423936\} \\
 b & 4.0000046 & 1.02\times 10^{-6}&  \{4.0000025,4.0000066\} \\
\end{array}$$

Also notice that, around the minima, the function is extremely flat : for example, for $n=0$, between $x=4.59251$ and $x=4.64282$ $f(x)$ is smaller than $1.001$ times the minimum value.

Comment: May I ask how $n^{th}$ minimum is close to $\frac{(4n+3)\pi}{2} \hspace{2mm}?$